# Consulta para ocultar columnas de una sola tabla

Tags: jquery

Disculpen, quería consultar lo siguiente:
Si tengo este código para ocultar ciertas columnas de una tabla:

```
$(document).ready(){
  $("#ocultar").on("click", function(){

       $(".ocultas").toggle(); $('td:nth-child(4)').toggle();
       $(".ocultas").toggle(); $('td:nth-child(5)').toggle();
       $(".ocultas").toggle(); $('td:nth-child(7)').toggle();
       $(".ocultas").toggle(); $('td:nth-child(8)').toggle();

   });
 });
```

El cual oculta la 4ta, 5ta, 7ma y 8va columna de una tabla.

¿Como hago en caso de tener otra tabla (de similares características) alineada a la misma altura, para que no se oculten las columnas de ambas tablas?

Gracias.
Gustavo

Answer (score 0):

Si le aplicas ids a las tablas no tienes más que relacionar este id en la función:

```
$(document).ready(){
  $("#ocultar").on("click", function(){

       $('#id_tabla td:nth-child(4)').toggle();

   });
 });
```

En este caso solo busca en la tabla con el id id_tabla.

Comment: Me funcionó perfecto. Muchas gracias. Saludos